# Building with default cl.exe or a custom bat

Tags: c++, visual-studio, batch-file, visual-studio-2013

Briefly: I'm looking to call a bat file either externally or via equivalent cl.exe builder and linker flags set within project/solution properties, and then start debugging directly from Visual Studio, cutting out my text editor and the constant swapping between applications I am currently doing.

--
I'm trying to change my workflow and make use of an IDE instead of multiple tools and swapping between them.  I'm currently editing in a text editor and building via a bat file. I then do any debugging in Visual Studio by calling: devenv mynewlybuilt.exe and hit F5.

My bat file is a simple call to cl.exe with some linker and compiler flags that I amend as needed. If it makes any difference, my project is one translation unit, I'm compiling just the one file.

Is there a simple way to build a C++ project in VS 2013 that uses whatever is passed to cl.exe by default and anything extra I wish to add?

The interface seems a nightmare and I'm having trouble working it out.

thanks.

Comment: Have you considered simply using C++ projects? Is right-clicking on a project, selecting properties and setting build options at will really such a nightmare?

Comment: well, that's where I naturally started, but there was a million and one things being passed to the compiler that actually prevented my project being built. I did manage to get it to build after some messing around and changing the flags but I still have little idea of what I did or why it didn't build in the first place. Yes. I'm aware that's a crux of using a large complex IDE but I figured there's must be a way to start from absolutely nothing and work forwards instead of backwards.

Comment: The easiest in the long run will be to create C++ project files (.vcxproj) to contain the build configuration.  Use MSDN documentation to learn where each option is located in the Visual Studio UI.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z1t1wy.aspx

Comment: thanks guys. Well, using something not dependant on VS means I can swap environments if needed. I found the most sane way was to create a project from existing code and select the use external build option and using the bat file that way.

Answer (score 0):

I found that simply starting a new project from existing code and selecting to use an external build tool is the easiest method.

It allows me to have the bat file open within VS as well, so I can add any flags as needed and then it can be used with other environments without having to export or, check the build.log or figure out what to pass to the command line to get an identical build. Not to mention individual project and even files having individual command line options.